# GCloud databaseType is set to CLOUD_FIRESTORE but I'm using RealTimeDatabase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My project uses the `RTB` but by mistake I activated Cloud Firestore. I don't use Firestore for anything and apparently there [isn't anyway to disable Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56685684/4833705).

I created a Cloud Task and when I run `$ gcloud app describe` it says `databaseType: CLOUD_FIRESTORE`. How can I change the `databaseType` to `RTB`?

```
$ gcloud app describe

authDomain: gmail.com
codeBucket: staging.xyz.appspot.com

databaseType: CLOUD_FIRESTORE // <------------------Here

defaultBucket: xyz.appspot.com
defaultHostname: xyz.ue.r.appspot.com
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
  useContainerOptimizedOs: true
gcrDomain: us.gcr.io
id: xyz
locationId: us-east1
name: apps/xyz
serviceAccount: xyz@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
servingStatus: SERVING
```

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create), I do have access to the `databaseType` field but I don't know how to change it or what value to change it to for the `RealTimeDatabase`. At the bottom, in blue, it says:

> Note: To create a Firestore in Datastore mode database , set
> databaseType to CLOUD_DATASTORE_COMPATIBILITY.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to change it to real time database, you might be able to managed this with the firebase sdk, as this tool is not present on the gcp side. Also what you could try is contacting Google in their [Issue Tracker System](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0) opening a feature request to create a way to manage this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I haven’t deployed anything yet because I’m still working on the code. Will this cause any issues with the the Cloud Task? I’ve been working on Cloud Tasks for 3 days now, I’ll be highly upset if I did all of this work for nothing. I’ll create an issue with them.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked all over and at the time of this writing there isn't a way to change the `databaseType`.

On a side note, after finally getting a successful Cloud Task to work and the function associated with it to also [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476854/4833705), it didn't prevent anything from working.

Basically as far as you only using the `RTB` and `databaseType` being set as `CLOUD_FIRESTORE`, **you have nothing to worry about.**